# laravel 5.3 send mail mailable

Tags: laravel-5.3, laravel-mail

I am trying to capture what I return the mail::send but it sends the mail and it arrives at me blank. What is the answer of this function?

```
$Sent =  Mail::send(new MailContact('', $to, $cc, $sub, '', $msn, '', $view));

if($Sent)
{
   return $Sent;
}
```

Comment: Please share your code with us.